# How to handle nested json data from restful wcf client call?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, asp.net-ajax

I am currently struck in a deadloop in handling the nested json data.
In my client side, if the data is

> **data: JSON.stringify({moduleIn: 5 })**

On my svc.cs 
I can handle and return it through a method

```
public int Testing (int moduleID)
{
 return moduleID; 
}
```

But if the data is

> **data: JSON.stringify({ moduleIDD: { moduleIn: 5 }}),**

I have no idea how do I handle this data...

Your help will be very appreciated.  :D

Answer (score 0):

Sighh, ending out I get to figure/find out the answer myself. For the future people who are doing such questions, the hint is : When doing nested json data, the main class need to have a sub class which contains all the parameters. The datamember/variable name in the main class needs to be defined same as the that client is calling..

Good luck, developers.